# Windows 7 Icon Placement

Tags: windows-7

I have just moved to Windows 7 and I am rather bothered by the icon placement in the details view.

In every version of windows before 7 the Icon followed the name of the file. However, someone at Microsoft decided that it would be a better idea to place the icon at the beginning of the details view row.

I prefer to have size as my first column and I am not alone. When I move it there the Icon does not move with the name like it used to.

I am wondering if anyone knows of a way to change the icon position?

Here is a picture of what I am talking about:

[image]

Comment: I confess I'm stumped. I don't see folders like you do and can't seem to be able to replicate your view under Windows 7

Answer (score 3):

For those wondering, this only shows when you reorder your columns. This applies when any column is moved to the first spot. The normal view, most people see the same ordering as other versions of Windows.

[image: Normal]

By placing your Size column first, you see your result:

[image: Weird]

I can't see a way of changing this icon position, other than keeping your Name column first. I'm assuming this is expected behavior and not a bug. It actually makes more sense this way when you sort your Type as your first column, as the Type will directly match the icon shown.

Probably not the answer you were hoping for, but the best you may be able to hope for  is a future registry tweak for changing this.

Comment: +1. Good catch, Guard. This one has got me puzzled and didn't think of column reordering. @Arriu The best option is to enrol on the Windows Feedback Program (http://wfp.microsoft.com/) and wait for an invitation.

Comment: Sorry, but I have to ask that: @Arriu are you really saying that having the icon NOT in the first column of the explorer detail view would have been the only reason for you to use Windows 7?